# Can anyone help me make a vertical navigation bar (Media Query)

Tags: html, css

I am just asking for your guys help on getting a vertical navigation bar, It's hard to find help over the internet when it's such a specific problem so any answers will be appreciated... this is for the media query at 480 x 800.

```
@media screen and (min-width:480px) and (max-width:800px){ #header{ height:100px; width:480px; } #nav{ padding: 15px; } #nav li ul{ list-style-type: none; padding: 15px; margin-left: 0; border-right:none; } #nav li a{ text-decoration: none; background-color: #ffffff; display: block; width: 8em; border-bottom:1px solid #eb322c; padding: 15px; }
```

Comment: Can you remove the unnecessary code and narrow it down to the specific problem..? a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with corresponding code will be even better..

Comment: TJ @media screen and (min-width:480px) and (max-width:800px){
#header{
height:100px;
width:480px;
}

#nav{ 
 padding: 15px;    
}


#nav li ul{
list-style-type: none;      
padding: 15px;      
margin-left: 0; 
border-right:none;

}

#nav li a{
text-decoration: none;            
background-color: #ffffff;      
display: block;      
width: 8em; 
border-bottom:1px solid #eb322c;
padding: 15px;    


}

Comment: instead of commenting, please edit and update the question with relevant info so that it's easy for the community to help you..

Answer (score 0):

change media Query css with this css

```
@media screen and (min-width:480px) and (max-width:800px){
#header{
height:100px;
width:480px;
}

#nav{ 
padding: 5px;
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
width: 150px;    
}
#nav ul {
padding: 5px;
border-left: 1px;
text-align: center;
 width: 150px;}

#nav li ul{
list-style-type: none;      
padding: 15px;      
margin-left: 0; 
border-right:none;

}

#nav li a{
text-decoration: none;            
background-color: #ffffff;      
display: block;      
width: 8em; 
border-bottom:1px solid #eb322c;
padding: 15px;    


}
```